# Calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}}-e}{x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Calculate
>
> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}}-e}{x}$$

**My Attempt:**

$$\lim_{x\to 0}e\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1}-1}{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1} \cdot \frac{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1}{x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}e.\frac{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1}{x}$$

I am not able to solve this further. I can easily use L-Hospital to show $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1}{x}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

How can I prove this without L-Hopital or Taylor expansions?

Comment: One can extend $f(x)=\ln(1+x)/x$, which is initially defined on $(-1,\infty)$ except for zero, to also be defined at zero and remain continuous, by setting $f(0)=1$. This is the derivative of $e^{f(x)}$ at zero, i.e. $e^{f(0)}f'(0)$.

Comment: Just an idea: $x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)$ so taking limits gives one-sided inequality I cannot find any suitable quadratic which can be set as an upper bound for $\ln(x)$ in some nbd of zero, so that I can apply Sandwich Theorem.

Comment: If you forbid Taylor then you need some more analysis. One option is to integrate the inequality $1-t<\dfrac{1}{1+t}<1-t+t^2$ in interval $[0,x]$ and use Squeeze Theorem. Another is put $x=e^t-1$ and evaluate the limit $\lim _{t\to 0}\dfrac {e^t-1-t}{t^2}$ using the definition $e^t=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+(t/n))^n$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I know the limit $\lim_{t\to{0}}\frac{e^t-1-t}{t^2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Then the substitution $x=e^t-1$ solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac12x^2+\dfrac13x^3+\cdots$$
then
\begin{align}
e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}
&= e^{1-\frac12x+\frac13x^2+\cdots} \\
&= e\left(e^{-\frac12x+\frac13x^2+\cdots}\right) \\
&= e\left(1+\left(-\frac12x+\frac13x^2+\cdots\right)+\dfrac12\left(-\frac12x+\frac13x^2+\cdots\right)^2+\cdots\right) \\
&= e\left(1-\dfrac12x+O(x^2)\right)
\end{align}
then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}}-e}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e\left(1-\dfrac12x+O(x^2)\right)-e}{x}=\color{blue}{-\dfrac12e}$$

Comment: 'How can I prove this without L-Hopital or Taylor expansions?' – Doesn't this use Taylor expansions?

Comment: @TobyMak I don't think this limit can be solved without L-Hopital or Taylor expansions. At least we need $\lim\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$ which needs more calculus and more more details.

Comment: That's fine, it's still a good method!